# VBA SQL "Insert Into" ERROR

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, excel

I got some annoying problem, and i already struggle for an hour fixing this thing..

so basically I try to Insert the Values of some Excel table into Access Database, But when i run my code, it keeps telling me that there is some missing operator, while i'm sure that my query is correct already.

I am not familiar with VBA or even SQL.

Here is My Code :

```vb
'Put Into Database
Dim ent As String
ent = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking").Cells(row, 1)
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Users\reza.ariefianto\Documents\Routing.mdb;"

Dim qq As ADODB.Command
Set qq = New ADODB.Command
qq.ActiveConnection = cn

Dim bid As String
bid = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFA Fill Form").Cells(11, 5)

Dim ttl As String
Dim cont As String
Dim typ As String

ttl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFA Fill Form").Cells(12, 5)
cont = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFA Fill Form").Cells(19, 5)
typ = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RFA Fill Form").Cells(15, 5)


Dim com As String
com = "insert into Entry([RFA],[Bid Number],[Title],[Contractor],[Type]) values (" & ent & "," & bid & "," & ttl & "," & cont & "," & typ & ");"

cn.Execute com

cn.Close
```

Comment: the query that you are creating is inserting string values. It's like you are doing: insert into test values (FOO,BAR) instead of: insert into test values ('FOO','BAR').
Could you try adding some "masked" single quotes?. For ex: ",'" & ttl & "',"

Comment: If you get an answer that solved your problem, mark it (click below the points buttons), instead of saying thanks to the author.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the values that are strings are wrapped in single quotes.

So let assume the first 2 values are strings and the rest are numbers, you need to speicyf it as

```
com = "insert into Entry([RFA],[Bid Number],[Title],[Contractor],[Type]) values ('" & ent & "','" & bid & "'," & ttl & "," & cont & "," & typ & ");"
```

Also, I would rather look at using the [Command.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, which would allow you to make use of [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, as to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)